# Android Open WebView inside Fragment - crash

Tags: android-fragments, android-webview

App need to open some websites when i touch buttons. There are 2 tabs (2 fragments) with different buttons (1 button = 1 link)
When i click a Button that need to open WebView (to open a link) application crash. I think, mistake is somewhere in AFragment.java

main.java (it's good 99,9%)

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static Context appContext;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        appContext = getApplicationContext();

       //ActionBar
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab PTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("One");
        ActionBar.Tab DTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Two");


        Fragment OneFragment = new AFragment();
        Fragment TwpFragment = new BFragment();

        PTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(OneFragment));
        DTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(TwoFragment));


        actionbar.addTab(PTab);
        actionbar.addTab(DTab);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

}


class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.appContext, "Reselected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

}
```

AFragment.java:

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class AFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  
                 SavedInstanceState) {                          
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
        }

        // On Button Click
        public void openIt(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), openPage.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
                     }
            }
```

openPage.class:

```
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class openPage extends Activity {

        WebView myWebView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.webview);


            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://safhkalfsd.com");

        }
    }
```

Layouts are fine 99,99%
i put
        android:onClick="openIt"
in afragment.xml inside Button 
THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
I need to put:

```
// On Button Click
public void openIt(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), openPage.class);
    startActivity(intent); 
             }
```

in MainActivity, not in 'AFragment'.

Comment: It's possible to keep this method in the fragment.  Just do getActivity().startActivity(intent);